# Custom formatter properties not initialized via "." when "format" specified

Tags: python, python-logging

I have a custom `logging.Formatter` that supports some additional properties, but they don't get initialized when I also specify the `format` property. If I comment the `format` line out, the `.` property properly initializes its custom properties.

```py
            "custom_formatter": {
                "()": MyFormatter,
                "style": "{",
                "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                "format": "<custom-format>", # <-- when removed, then the '.' works
                ".": {
                    "custom_property": "value"
                }
            }
```

Why doesn't the `.` work when `format` is used?

The formatter is implemented like this:

```py
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    custom_property: str = "."

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        # ...
        return super().format(record)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the *bug*. Apparently the name of the property has changed from `format` to  `fmt` and old examples show `format` in their configs and when this is used, the code that processes the `.` dictionary isn't executed as the intialization falls back to an exception handler and skips the rest of the code that would normally execute the `.`

This is the error handler:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/config.py#L670

```py
    def configure_formatter(self, config):
        """Configure a formatter from a dictionary."""
        if '()' in config:
            factory = config['()'] # for use in exception handler
            try:
                result = self.configure_custom(config)
            except TypeError as te:
                if "'format'" not in str(te):
                    raise
                #Name of parameter changed from fmt to format.
                #Retry with old name.
                #This is so that code can be used with older Python versions
                #(e.g. by Django)
                config['fmt'] = config.pop('format')
                config['()'] = factory
                result = self.configure_custom(config)
```

And this is the code that throws the error on the line `result = c(**kwargs)` thus skipping the processing of `props` as the `config` no longer contains `.` because it has been popped from the dictionary during the first try!

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/config.py#L480

```py
    def configure_custom(self, config):
        """Configure an object with a user-supplied factory."""
        c = config.pop('()')
        if not callable(c):
            c = self.resolve(c)
        props = config.pop('.', None) # <-- removes '.' making it impossible to use it on the second try!
        # Check for valid identifiers
        kwargs = {k: config[k] for k in config if valid_ident(k)}
        result = c(**kwargs)
        if props:
            for name, value in props.items():
                setattr(result, name, value)
        return result
```

The `props = config.pop('.', None)` line should come after `result = c(**kwargs)`.

Comment: I've reported it on GitHub as [Issue 110875](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/110875)